# Fields' layer listed into a QListWidget in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I use a **QgsMapLayerComboBox** nested with a **QgsFieldComboBox** in Qt. 
The problem is that I can **select only one field** with the `field combobox` and I need to select several fields.

```
self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox_2.layerChanged['QgsMapLayer*'].connect(self.dlg.mFieldComboBox_2.setLayer)
```

That's why instead of using a `Combobox` I would like to replace the `FieldComboBox` by a `QListWidget`.

How can I fill a `QListWidget` by the list of field of the Layer selected by `MapLayerCombobox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example which you can run in an editor in the Python console. This should provide you with an example of adding items to the list widget from a list of field names from the current layer in the map layer combo box and updating the fields whenever the layer is changed; allowing multiple selections with:

```py
self.fld_list.setSelectionMode(QListWidget.ExtendedSelection)
```

clearing the selection, and retrieving the `QgsField` objects from the list widget selected items. My example creates a dictionary of field names and field objects by calling the `text()` method on the `QListWidgetItem` objects returned by the `selectedItems()` method.

```py
class Dlg(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.cb_layer = QgsMapLayerComboBox()
        self.cb_layer.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.VectorLayer)
        self.cb_layer.layerChanged.connect(self.layer_changed)
        self.fld_list = QListWidget(self)
        self.fld_list.setSelectionMode(QListWidget.ExtendedSelection)
        self.fld_list.addItems([f.name() for f in self.cb_layer.currentLayer().fields()])
        self.btn1 = QPushButton('Clear selection', self)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.fld_list.clearSelection())
        self.te1 = QTextEdit(self)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton('Retrieve selected fields', self)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.get_selection)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cb_layer, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.fld_list, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1, 2, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.te1, 3, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn2, 4, 0)

    def layer_changed(self, layer):
        self.fld_list.clear()
        flds = [f.name() for f in layer.fields()]
        self.fld_list.addItems(flds)

    def get_selection(self):
        inds = [i.text() for i in self.fld_list.selectedItems()]
        flds = {}
        for i in inds:
            flds[i] = [f for f in self.cb_layer.currentLayer().fields() if f.name() == i][0]
        self.te1.setText(str(flds))


W = Dlg()
W.show()
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: this solution is really perfect ! it helps to understand how it works, thanks so much

Comment: You're most welcome!